# Regular Expression group repeated letters

Tags: ruby, regex, repeat

I am trying to group all the repeated letters in a string.

Eg:

```
"aaaaaaabbbbbbbbc" => [['aaaaaaa'],['bbbbbbbb'],['c']]
```

Using logic and Ruby, the only way I could find to reach my intention was:

```
.scan(/(?:a+|A+)|(?:b+|B+)|(?:c+|C+)| ..... (?:y+|Y+)|(?:z+|Z+))
```

where `...` are the other alphabet letters.

There is a way to Dry that RegEx?
I used backtrace `(\1)` too, but it doesn't match the single words and it doesn't return me the exact letters match => `(\w+)\1` => `[['aa'],['bb']]`

Uhm, am I wrong to use the regular expressions for this case and I should use Ruby methods with iterations?

I will glad to hear your opinion :)
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want `[['aaaaaaa'], ['bbbbbbbb'], ['c']]` and not just `['aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbb', 'c']`?

Comment: The answers reflect some confusion about your question. Do you want the return value for `"abab"` to be `["a", "b", "a", "b"]` or `["aa", "bb"]`?

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can upvote the answer you've selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use another capturing group to catch the repeated characters.

```
s.scan(/((\w)\2*)/).map(&:first)
# => ["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "c"]
```

Comment: Interesting! You could instead write `map(&:first)`. The way [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan) deals with groups is like that double-edged sword you are holding: it's either convenient or--as here--an irritating impediment.

Comment: @Cary Thanks as always :-)

Comment: I like this solution, but I also I want to understand it. Could someone put into words how the regexp is set up, especially '\2*' ? Thanks!

Comment: @Krisztina in regex, we use `\<group_number>` to refer the corresponding captured chars, say `\1` refers to the chars which are capturing by the first capturing group `()` whereas the `\2` refers to the 2nd capturing group. Likewise it goes on. So here `(\w)` should capture all the word chars and `(\w)\1*` matches all word chars as well as the following 0 or more repeated chars. say it matches `b`, `nn`, `b` in `bnnb` input string. Since the `scan` func returns only the captured chars, I again wrap the whole regex inside another group.

Comment: But if we use the `\1`, it still refers to the first group but we want the second one that's why I used `\2`

Answer (score 2):

One more solution without regexp :)

```
"aaaaaaabbbbbbbbc".chars.group_by(&:itself).values.map { |e| [e.join] }
 #=> [["aaaaaaa"], ["bbbbbbbb"], ["c"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using a regex you could take a look to [`Enumerable#slice_when`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when):

```
string = "aaaaaaabbbbbbbbc"
p string.chars.sort.slice_when { |a, b| a != b }.map { |element| element.join.split }
# [["aaaaaaaa"], ["bbbbbbbb"], ["c"]]
```

Comment: Isn't `map(&:join)` sufficient? I suggest using `each_char` rather than `chars` whenever it is followed by an enumerable (to avoid creating an unnecessary intermediate array).

Comment: It's because of the output he added @Cary, only `map(&:join)` gives `["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "c"]`.

Comment: Oh, yes, that! In that case `map { |element| [element.join] }` may be easier to understand.

Comment: I thought about it also with Alex's answer :), thanks for the `each_char` suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few other ways ways to do that. All return `["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "c"]`. If `[["aaaaaaa"], ["bbbbbbbb"], ["c"]]` is truly wanted (I can't imagine why), that's a simple extra step using `map`.

```
s.each_char.chunk(&:itself).map(&:join)

s.each_char.chunk_while { |a,b| b == a }.map(&:join)

s[1..-1].each_char.with_object([s[0]]) {|c,a| c == a.last[0] ? (a.last<<c) : a<< c}

s.gsub(/(.)\1*/).with_object([]) { |t,a| a << t }
```

In the last of these, [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) does not have a block, so it returns an enumerator (and does not perform any character replacement.) This use of `gsub` can be used to advantage in many situations.